# For noncentral chi-square in scipy, how is the input 'nc' defined?

Tags: python, scipy

scipy.stats.ncx2 implements some functions for the non-central chi-square distribution. There is one input 'nc' to these functions.

Suppose there are k independent random numbers from N(mu,1)

My question is should nc be defined as k*mu^2 or \sqrt(k*mu^2).

I am asking this because from Wikipedia, it explicitly states follows:

"Alternatively, the pdf can be written as

exp(-(nc+df)/2) * 1/2 * (x/nc)**((df-2)/4) * I(df-2)/2

where the non-centrality parameter in this formula is the square root of sum of square."

And in the documentation of scipy.stats.ncx2, the pdf has exactly the same form as above.

So should the input 'nc' be the sum of squrares, or the the square root of sum of square.

Is there some way to numerically verify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meanings of the noncentrality parameter in those two representations of the PDF in the wikipedia page are the same.  They haven't changed the definition of λ, which is the sum of the squares of the means of normal distributions.

Here's a script that generates the same curves as the plot in the wikipedia page.  The colored lines are computed using `scipy.stats.ncx2.pdf`, and the gray lines are computed using the first 10 terms of the infinite series given in the wikipedia page.  The plot verifies that these are just different expressions for the same value.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ncx2, chi2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def approx_pdf(x, k, lam):
    p = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=np.float64)
    f = 1
    for i in range(10):
        p += np.exp(-lam/2) * (lam/2)**i * chi2.pdf(x, k + 2*i) / f
        f *= (i + 1)
    return p

# df == k on wikipedia
# nc == lambda on wikipedia

x = np.linspace(0, 8, 400)

linestyle = '-'
for df in [2, 4]:
    for nc in [1, 2, 3]:
        plt.plot(x, ncx2.pdf(x, df, nc), linestyle=linestyle,
                 label=f'k = {df}, λ = {nc}')
        plt.plot(x, approx_pdf(x, df, nc), 'k', alpha=0.1, linewidth=6)
    linestyle = '--'

plt.title("Noncentral chi-square distribution\nProbability density function")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.legend(shadow=True)
plt.grid(alpha=0.3)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The plot generated by the script:

[image: plot]

---

Here's another short script, to demonstrate that the noncentrality parameter is, in fact, the sum of the squares of the means of the normal distributions.  It generates a large sample of values, with each value being the sum of the square of three normal random variates with means 1, 1.5 and 3, respectively.  The distribution of this sample should be a noncentral chi-square with 3 degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter equal to the sum of the squares of the means.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ncx2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Means of the normal distributions.
mu = np.array([1, 1.5, 3])

k = len(mu)          # df in scipy.stats.ncx2
lam = (mu**2).sum()  # nc in scipy.stats.ncx2

# The distribution of sample should be a noncentral chi-square
# with len(mu) degrees of freedom and noncentrality sum(mu**2).
sample = (np.random.normal(loc=mu, size=(100000, k))**2).sum(axis=1)

# Plot the normalized histogram of the sample.
plt.hist(sample, bins=60, density=True, alpha=0.4)

# This plot of the PDF should match the histogram.
x = np.linspace(0, sample.max(), 800)
plt.plot(x, ncx2.pdf(x, k, lam))

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.grid(alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

As you can see in the plot, the theoretical PDF matches the normalized histogram of the sample.

[image: plot histogram and PDF]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Does this mean that the statement in the Wikipedia page "where the non-centrality parameter in this formula is the square root of sum of square" is wrong?

Comment: @Paradox, yes, it looks like that statement is incorrect.